# Google analytics goal fired on ajax success

Tags: jquery

so the code I have is very basic and looks like this...

```
    jQuery(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, opt){
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxxx']);

        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/goal1']);
    });
```

I have this in my footer

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxxx']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);


  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl'  : 'http://www')  + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

And yet it does not work, any suggestions on how i could get this to work is appreciated, also I did a alert to make sure the ajax success works and it worked so i am 100% positive it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll have to write it this way

```
var _gaq = window._gaq || [];
```

Else, _gaq is undefined at this point because of variable Hoisting in Javascript.

Comment: OMG IT WORKED, IT ACTUALLY WORKED!!!! I have been trying to crack this one for a whole 5mins!!! J/k I've kinda been stuck on this for hours, thank you man!

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate these 2 lines:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxxx']);
```

They're clearing the analytics object. You should just have the push in the success handler.